# no refresca tabla despúes de hacer una consulta reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Estoy aprendiendo react y tengo un crud sencillo donde todas las peticiones funcionan correctamente y se ven reflejadas en la bbdd, el problema es que en react no refresca esos cambios automáticamente, para poder verlos tengo que recargar la pagina entera, y no logro ver donde esta el problema, alguna ayuda?

Department.js

```
function Department() {

  const baseUrl = "https://localhost:44321/api/Department";
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [modalInsertar, setModalInsertar] = useState(false);
  const [depSelected, setDepSelected] = useState({
    id: "",
    name: "",
    UserCreated: "",
  });

 useEffect(() => {
    peticionGet();      //Obtengo lista de departamentos
  }, []);

const handleChange = (e) => {                  //Obtengo valores del formulario
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setDepSelected({
      ...depSelected,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
```

Tabla (return) :

```
<tbody>
          {data.map((departamentos) => (                
            <tr key={departamentos.id}>
              <td>{departamentos.id}</td>
              <td>{departamentos.name}</td>
              <td>
                <button
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                  onClick={seleccionaDep("Editar")}
                >
                  Editar
                </button>{" "}
                <button
                  className="btn btn-danger"
                  onClick={seleccionaDep("Eliminar")}
                >
                  Eliminar
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: He encontrado una simple forma de mostrar los cambios en tiempo real agregando a las funciones asincronas POST,PUT y DELETE un llamado al GET, de esta forma veo en tiempo real los cambios, aunque creo que es un parche y no soluciona el problema de fondo...

Comment: Puedes contestar tu propia pregunta, saludos

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una simple forma de mostrar los cambios en tiempo real agregando a las funciones asíncronas POST,PUT y DELETE un llamado al GET, de esta forma veo en tiempo real los cambios, aunque creo que es un parche y no soluciona el problema de fondo... –